# How to call unmarshal() in camel processor?

Tags: java, apache-camel, unmarshalling

Camel Route:

```
from(source)          
    .idempotentConsumer(simple("${in.header.CamelFilePath}"), redisIdempotentRepository)
    .process(pgpDecryptionProcessor)
    .to(destination);
```

PGPDecryptionProcessor:

```
public class PGPDecryptionProcessor implements Processor {

  @Autowired
  private PGPEncryptionManager pgpEncryptionManager;

  @Override
  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
     //do something to check whether it is encrypted 
     //get corrsponding dataformat for decryption
     processDefinition.unmarshal(dataFormat);  //How do i get processDefinition here
    }
  }
}
```

I need to call `ProcessDefinition.unmarshal(dataformat)`. How can I get the `ProcessDefinition` object inside process method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly call unmarshal of the dataformat with `Exchange` and `Exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class)` as another param:

```
dataformat.unmarshal(exchange, exachange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class));
```

You don't need to call the `ProcessDefinition.unmarshal()`; `ProcessDefinition` only defines which dataformat to use and finally when your message comes in what happens is the `Dataformat.unmarshal()` method is called with `Exchange` and `Body InputStream`.

Comment: From where to get dataformat object?